# Set vboxsf write permissions of shared folder of VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, filesystems, ntfs, file-permissions, shared-folders

I use VirtualBox on Windows 7. In my Debian 8 (testing) guest I have a shared folder with the Windows 7 host NTFS file system.

I mount it via fstab at boot time with

```
winfolder  /mnt/winfolder vboxsf  defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022 0  0
```

Unfortunately some directories are still not writable:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 me me  24K Dec 19 15:06 Software/
dr-xr-xr-x 1 me me  24K Mar  8 11:40 Videos/
```

Why is that and how can I make these folders (like Video) writable and get write access to them?

Answer (score 0):

Your mount options use an umask that prevent shared files and directories to be created with the "group writable" attribute.

You should use "umask=0002" (instead of 0022)

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't make any difference. But I think I need 022. Anyway I have removed too much zeros which I had.

Comment: I didn't see that the Videos folder doesn't have "user" write permission, I saw the "group" write permission missing and I thought that was the problem... Anyway, did you check the folders' permissions under windows to see what difference there was between the Software and Videos folders?